# C# String to Javascript var

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, webforms

I have a string in my C# code-behind file in ASP.NET:

```
string data = "Data that is populated"; 
//Note: A method populates the actual data
```

I need to be able to convert this string to a JavaScript var. I know that using a Razor file is a common way to go and there are several questions on this topic, but I am unsure how to do this with a code-behind file, nor have I full understood the previous questions and answers.

Comment: What exactly is a code behind file? A .aspx.cs file? If so, why don't you do it from the .aspx file directly?

Comment: Do you need to send it to the browser?

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto yes, that what a code-behind file is, what exactly do you mean by directly with a aspx file?

Comment: @PoulBak I need to pass it in as a parameter for a JavaScript function

Answer (score 2):

In a case like this, I set a HiddenField.Value to the string's value, like this, in aspx:

```
<asp:HiddenField ID="HiddenField1" runat="server" />
```

and then in code behind:

```
HiddenField1.Value = "some string";
```

Now in JavaScript you can read that value and pass it to your function:

```
var myValue = document.getElementById('HiddenField1').value;
myFuction(myValue);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this code

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string scriptCode = @"
        <script>
        let text = {0}; 
        alert(text);
        </script>";

    string message = "Hello World!";
    scriptCode = string.Format(scriptCode, HttpUtility.JavaScriptStringEncode(message, true));

    RegisterStartupScript("AlertCode", scriptCode);
}
```

The function `RegisterStartupScript` embeds JavaSript code into the page. Use `JavaScriptStringEncode()` to convert a string into a JavaScript string representation to use in that JavaScript code.